# View app data file in Android File Transfer

Tags: android, file-io, storage

I cannot find the file I created in my android app in Android File Transfer under /Android/data. My goal is to copy/edit a config file to the app data folder while I develop the app, and then later link it to a Google Drive file. But, even when I write a file in the app with the following:

```
FileOutPutStream outputStream;
try {
    outputStream = mAppContext.openFileOutput("my_config.json", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE);
    outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
    Log.d("WRITE", "FILE WRITTEN!");
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the debug log message the the file was written, but I cannot find it in Android File Transfer (there isn't even a directory for my app). I have also tried cd-ing into it from adb shell, as well as rebooting the device. What is the best way to quickly transfer a file into and out of an app directory? I am running 4.4.2 Kit Kat.

Comment: You might want to check _Context.getFilesDir()_ method to re-check where this file is supposedly created.

Comment: So that was a great point, it was actually stored in /data/data/<appname>. But I couldn't figure out a way to actually get data here. So I ended up using Context.getExternalFilesDir() because there are no special permissions there.